# Automating a label to provide sum of integers from textboxes

Tags: c#, automation, label

I have multiple textboxes which will contain numbers provided by the user. At the bottom of all the text boxes, I would like to have a label which will provide the sum total of all the numbers from the textboxes above. No button will be needed, the label will update automatically as the user types in the textboxes. Here's an example that I borrowed from the internet.

http://tinypic.com/r/ev5ely/8

Notice the numbers were updated automatically without a button_click method. Any suggestions to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The textboxes raise events when their contents change.  Subscribe to these events and recalculate the sum and set the label value?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too, but I'm not sure how to practically apply it. @CharlesMager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a groupbox and add your all involved textboxes and label into this groupbox. For instance, the name of your groupbox is Groupbox1.

Add TextChanged event to your textbox either manually through properties or programmatically as represented below:

```
TextBox1.TextChanged += onTextChanged;
TextBox2.TextChanged += onTextChanged;
...........
TextBoxN.TextChanged += onTextChanged;
```

Now in onTextChanged event,

```
protected void onTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    try{
            int sum = 0;//your sum
            foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)//iterate over each control insied groupbox
            {
                if (c as TextBox != null)//if controller is a textbox instance
                {
                    sum += Convert.ToInt32(c.Text);//you can use float long or double datatype according to your need
                }
            }
            Label1.Text = sum.ToString();//sum of the integers in all text boxes
        }
        catch( Exception ex){
             //your exception handling for num integer input goes here
        }
}
```

One more thing,

Comment: In case of an empty textbox or a textbox with non-numerical contents you should definetly wrap only the `Convert.ToInt32` call in a `try-ctach` block. In your code, if one conversion fails, the whole function is being aborted, even if there might be other textboxes left with legit numbers in them

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt that's why i wrapped the whole event handling thing within a try-catch block

Comment: Thanks a lot @NZeta520 ! This is amazing! Question though, for the first part, where you mentioned the textchanged, do I add the code `TextBox1.TextChanged += onTextChanged;` to the textchanged event for textbox1 only? Textbox 2 will have a textchanged event of `TextBox2.TextChanged += onTextChanged;`, etc.? Thanks!

Comment: @Kayla All textboxes will refer to the same event. You are welcome :)

Comment: @NZeta520 I added an "Answer" below. Really, it's a question for you, but I posted there due to limited space in the "Add Comment" section.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event handler to the control in two ways.
1. During the design time in properties windows by searching for the event such as "TextChanged" and eventually adding your event handler "onTextChanged".
2. During runtime as i have demonstrated earlier,
   textbox1.TextChanged += onTextChanged
However, you have done something like this

```
//this wrong and will not work at all
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox3.TextChanged +=  onTextChanged;
}
```

For example you must have added event handler "textBox2_TextChanged" to "TextChanged" event of "textbox2". Interestingly inside this event handler you have added another eventhandler "onTextChanged" for the same event. Notice "+=" which means multicast delegate (delegate which wraps up more than one method). So each time you type something inside the textboxes, this event will be called and eventually onTextChanged will be added. As a result, the event will be stacked up due to "+=" operator. So first time when you type something in the textbox(for all) nothing will happen but next time when you type something, both your "textBox2_TextChanged" and "onTextChanged" will be fired and again "onTextChanged" event will be added and so on. Hence, this isn't the ideal place to assign events to your controls. You assign these event somewhere else such as FormLoad which will be called only one time at any cost during the form initialization. Also, as I've mentioned you can assign these events in the properties windows as well during the design time.